# Encrypt with JavaScript and decrypt with Java based on shared key

Tags: java, javascript, encryption, public-key-encryption

Please suggest the best way in which we encrypt in JavaScript and decrypt in java based on shared key.

Comment: "java-script"? Really? (I've fixed it for you.)

Comment: Javascript encryption is bad idea: http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Is the encryption done in the browser using JS from the web? Is is served with TLS?

Comment: @Eugene: JS encryption is not a bad idea if it is for a standalone application, a NodeJS server … It is generally/probably useless embedded on a webpage served over plain (non TLS-ed) HTTP.

Comment: @ysdx TLS doesn't save encryption in browser from hijacking because the overall environment is not secure. I agree that in node.js encryption does make sense, but there's no node.js tag or reference in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few shared-key encryption libraries out there. Just make sure to use one that you can run in Java. One I've found useful is [Daniel Rench's Blowfish library](http://dren.ch/js_blowfish/).

I would be generally be very reluctant to do anything serious with any in-browser implementation, mainly because I seriously doubt the peer review of JS encryption is thorough enough to adequately trust. I completely dismiss the criticisms of JS-based encryption as being inherently weaker than other client-based tool, though. Just because you can debug a JS script in the browser and is the code exists in plaintext doesn't mean it's any different inherently than any other client-based encryption system. "Easier" does not mean "less secure". *Any* encryption software that runs outside of a secure system is equally at risk of tampering and manipulation no matter what. And, if implemented correctly, a JS cypher tool shares the same weaknesses of all similar tools and no more.